# SignInWithAppleButton loops after correct password is entered, the button ends up being grey once pressed and goes back to blue shortly after

Tags: swiftui, firebase-authentication, sign-in-with-apple

I'm having trouble trying to identify where I could be potentially missing something in my code, there are no errors anywhere and the `SignInWithAppleButton` allows me to enter my password but once I enter the correct password it just loops and doesn't actually sign in user. I'm currently using Xcode 12.5, signed in with the Apple ID already on the simulator phone and running iOS 14.5.I set breakpoints at the specific SignInWithApple button closure and the onCompletion closure doesn't run

Here is my SignUpView Code

```
   import SwiftUI 
    import AuthenticationServices 
    import Firebase 
         struct SignUpView: View {
        @StateObject var loginData = Authentication()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            let backgroundColor: Color = Color.init(red: 0.332, green: 0.087, blue: 0.839)
            backgroundColor.ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            Text("Welcome to GiftMe!  ").font(.title).fontWeight(.heavy).shadow(color: .black, radius: 10, x: 0.0, y: 0.0).position(x:200, y: 70).foregroundColor(.white)
            
            Image("logo").clipShape(Ellipse())
                .shadow(color: .black, radius: 10)
                .animation(.easeIn(duration: 2.0)).position(x: 200.0, y: 250.0)
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 30){
                Spacer()
                
                // Apple Button
                SignInWithAppleButton { (request) in
                    // requesting parameters from apple login
                    loginData.nonce = randomNonceString()
                    request.requestedScopes = [.email, .fullName]
                    request.nonce = sha256(loginData.nonce)
                } onCompletion: { (result) in
                    // getting error or success
                    switch result{
                    case .success(let user):
                        print("success")
                        // Login w/ Firebase
                        guard let credential = user.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential else{
                            print("error w/ firebase")
                            return
                        }
                        loginData.authenticate(credential: credential)
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }.signInWithAppleButtonStyle(.white)
                .frame(height: 55)
                .clipShape(Capsule())
                .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                
                Spacer()
            }.offset(x: 0.0, y: 100.0).padding()
        }.ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            SignUpView()
        }
    }
```

Here is my Sign-up/sign-in (Authentication) model code which has no errors. All of this code is from this YouTube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bYMc2WUhwk
I've been through the video 6+ times and still can't find out why my code doesn't login directly

```
import Foundation
import CryptoKit
import AuthenticationServices
import Firebase

class Authentication: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var nonce = ""
    
    func authenticate(credential: ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential){
        // get token
        guard let token = credential.identityToken else {
            print("error w/ firebase")
            return
        }
        
        guard let tokenString = String(data: token, encoding: .utf8) else{
            print("error w/ token")
            return
        }
        
        let firebaseCredential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com", idToken: tokenString, rawNonce: nonce)
        
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: firebaseCredential) { (result, err) in
            
            if let error = err {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            print("user successfully logged in")
        }
    }
}

func sha256(_ input: String) -> String {
    let inputData = Data(input.utf8)
    let hashedData = SHA256.hash(data: inputData)
    let hashString = hashedData.compactMap {
        return String(format: "%02x", $0)
    }.joined()
    return hashString
}

func randomNonceString(length: Int = 32) -> String {
    precondition(length > 0)
    let charset: Array<Character> =
        Array("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-._")
    var result = ""
    var remainingLength = length
    
    while remainingLength > 0 {
        let randoms: [UInt8] = (0 ..< 16).map { _ in
            var random: UInt8 = 0
            let errorCode = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 1, &random)
            if errorCode != errSecSuccess {
                fatalError("Unable to generate nonce. SecRandomCopyBytes failed with OSStatus \(errorCode)")
            }
            return random
        }
        
        randoms.forEach { random in
            if remainingLength == 0 {
                return
            }
            
            if random < charset.count {
                result.append(charset[Int(random)])
                remainingLength -= 1
            }
        }
    }
    
    return result
}
```